# Executing a javascript stored in a Database column using Pentaho

Tags: javascript, pentaho, pentaho-spoon

I have a Table name `"EXTRACT_NAMES"` with the below columns and sample value.

```
column 1 : NAME_REFERENCE (sample value  : "BALDH003")

column 2 : CONFIG_KEY (sample value : "NAME_REFERENCE.getString()")
```

In my `javascript`, I am trying to read the `"CONFIG_KEY"`.

```
var testValue = eval(CONFIG_KEY.getString());

alert(testValue);
```

Expected output : `BALDH003`

Actual output   : `NAME_REFERENCE.getString()`

How to resolve the above string interpolation issue?.

Comment: you should do `var testValue = eval(NAME_REFERENCE.getString());`  if you want to get `BALDH003`

Comment: No. I need to get the value from the "CONFIG_KEY" to keep this configurable. I want to extend this approach for any addition of new attributes.

Comment: Can you please post the value of `CONFIG_KEY.getString()` (for example by running `console.log(CONFIG_KEY.getString())`)?

Answer (score -2):

Maybe your answer will be shown by running this snippet:

```
var NAME_REFERENCE = "BALDH003()";
var CONFIG_KEY = "NAME_REFERENCE";
var testValue = eval(eval(CONFIG_KEY));
console.log(testValue);


    function BALDH003() {
    return "hi";
    }
```